# Algorithm for approximate number finding

Tags: algorithm, search, logarithm

Consider the following game:

- John and Peter agree on a number *n*.
- John chooses a number *x* between 1 and *n*.
- Peter makes a series of guesses *k* between 1 and *n*. For each guess:

  - If *x*/2 ≤ *k* ≤ 2*x*, then Peter wins.
  - Otherwise, John tells Peter whether *x* is less than *k*.

Peter wants to win in the fewest number of guesses.

There are obvious solutions requiring worst-case *O*(log *n*) guesses, but a friend told me that there's a solution with better asymptotic behavior than that. Is my friend right?

Comment: How many tries does Peter have?

Comment: Only one) You _should_ win after a number of questions. And the problem is how many questions do you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is right. The possible values of *x* can be partitioned into the ranges {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,…,19,20}, {21,22,…,83,84}, etc., where each range has a single "central" element that covers the whole range; for example, if *x* is anywhere between 21 and 84, then *k* = 42 is a winning guess. There are *O*(log *n*) such ranges, and Peter can use binary search to find the right range in *O*(log log *n*) guesses.

Comment: Hmm, I was analyzing the case for n = 1000 and x = 1, and after a quick calculation it seems to me that 5 steps are needed to get to the solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NiVeR: For *n* = 1000, one valid partition is [1, 4], [5, 20], [21, 84], [85, 340], and [341, 1000]. Using binary search, you first guess 42 (to cover [21, 84]) and are told that *x* is less than 42/2; let's assume you next, unluckily, guess 10 (to cover [5, 20]), and are told that *x* is less than 10/2; finally you guess 2 (to cover [1, 4]) and win. So, three steps in the worst case.

Comment: Good, I upvodeted. I have done a different (suboptimal) execution.